# rake db:migrate:up doesnt works anymore in Rails 3.2.13?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Does the command rake db:migrate:up  works in Rails 3.2.13 ?    What is the equivalent/opposite of rake db:rollback?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is 
    `db:migrate:redo`

Check out http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#rolling-back for more details.